# Need help creating a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm having issues trying to write a stored procedure that removes data from tables. I have 3 tables `[SessionOrderHolidayMapping]`, `[SessionHolidayMapping]` and `[cfgSchedule]` that I am trying to remove data from.

Each of these tables has a common column `[SessionId]`. What's happening is each `SessionId` has certain order days, no order days, holidays and no order holidays associated with it. What I need is when the user selects dates/holidays they don't want associated with that `[SessionId]` any more, it gets removed from the data base.

Here are the tables with the columns that need to be updated:

```
[SessionOrderHolidayMapping]   [SessionHolidayMapping]   [cfgScheudle]
----------------------------   -----------------------   --------------
[SessionId]                     [SessionId]               [SessionId]
[HolidayName]                   [HolidayName]             [OrderDays]
                                                          [NoOrderDays]

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[RemoveGlobalOrderDays]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[RemoveGlobalOrderDays]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RemoveGlobalOrderDays]
    @SessionId INT,
    @SelectedHolidays NVARCHAR(50),
    @SelectedOrderHolidays NVARCHAR(50),
    @OrderDays NVARCHAR(50),
    @NoOrderDays NVARCHAR(50)
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WHERE [cfgSchedule].[SessionId] = @SessionID

    DELETE FROM [cfgSchedule] (OrderDays, NoOrderDays)

    SELECT Item, @SessionId 
    FROM SplitString(@OrderDays, ',') AS OrderDays 
    WHERE Item <> ''

    SELECT Item, @SessionId 
    FROM SplitString(@NoOrderDays, ',') AS NoOrderDays 
    WHERE Item <> ''

    DELETE FROM [SessionHolidayMapping] 
    WHERE [SessionID] = @SessionID

    DELETE FROM [SessionHolidayMapping] (HolidayName, SessionId)

    SELECT Item, @SessionId 
    FROM SplitString(@SelectedHolidays, ',') AS Holidays 
    WHERE Item <> ''

    DELETE FROM [SessionOrderHolidayMapping] 
    WHERE [SessionID] = @SessionID

    DELETE FROM [SessionOrderHolidayMapping] (HolidayName, SessionId)

    SELECT Item, @SessionId 
    FROM SplitString(@SelectedOrderHolidays, ',') AS Holidays 
    WHERE Item <> ''
END
GO
```

Comment: What kind of issues are you running into? Could you post the error or problem you are getting please :)

Comment: @KyleMcphillips the rest of my stored procedure didn't post, thanks for catching that. I've tried many variations of the above stored procedure and I just can't quite getting it working

Comment: No problem, thanks for updating. I'll take a look and see if anything catches my eye

Comment: What does it do when you try running this as is?

Comment: Some syntax errors: Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure RemoveGlobalOrderDays, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 3]
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure RemoveGlobalOrderDays, Line 26 [Batch Start Line 3]
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure RemoveGlobalOrderDays, Line 35 [Batch Start Line 3]
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: Nothing is underlined so when I try to change where it says the errors are at I end up creating more.

Comment: I don't believe the syntax `DELETE FROM [table] (column_list)` is supported... what are you trying to do with that? For example, `DELETE FROM [cfgSchedule] (OrderDays, NoOrderDays)`.

Comment: I agree with Jeff, the delete syntax is generally "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the syntax `DELETE FROM [cfgSchedule] (OrderDays, NoOrderDays)` isn't supported.

If you want to delete the whole row, remove the column list. If you want to delete only those columns (i.e. replace them with nulls), use an UPDATE statement.

EDIT: Another issue I see above is this dangling WHERE clause that doesn't appear to be attached to anything:

```
WHERE [cfgSchedule].[SessionId] = @SessionID
```